# Kivy have a clickable button on a canvas draw

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to have people draw a clock and when they are done to click the submit button and it will take a screenshot. When I use the canvas to draw I can not use the button anymore.

Is there a way to place the button on top of the canvas so that it is still clickable?

main.py

```
class Clock(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas.before:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y), width = 2)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("released", touch)
```

clock.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<Clock>:
    FloatLayout
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .5, .5, .5, .5
            Line:
                width: 50
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"top": .9, "center_x": .5}
            size_hint: 1, .1
            text: "Draw a clock."
            font_size: 25
        BoxLayout:
            id: myexport
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"top": .1, "right": 1}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            text:
                "Submit"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("animals1")
                myexport.export_to_png("Clock.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Clock` class methods, you need to call the `super` methods in order to get the event properly propagated:

```
class Clock(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas.before:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y), width = 2)
        return super(Clock, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print(touch)
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)
        return super(Clock, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("released", touch)
        return super(Clock, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```